# Writing UTF-8 friendly parsers in python

Tags: python, unicode-string, python-2.7

I wrote a simple file parser and writer, but then I came across an article talking about the importance of unicode and then it occurred to me that I'm assuming the input file is ascii encoded, which may not be the case all the time, though it would be rare in my situation.

In those rare cases, I would expect UTF-8 encoded files.

Is there a way to work with UTF-8 files by simply changing how I read and write? All I do with the strings is store them and then write them out, so I just need to make sure I can read them, store them, and write them properly.

Furthermore, would I have to treat ascii and UTF-8 files separately and write different functions for each? I have not worked with anything other than ascii files yet and only read about handling unicode.

Comment: ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so you shouldn't need two sets of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python natively supports Unicode. If you directly read and write from the first file to the second, then no data is lost as it copies the bytes verbatim. However, if you decode the string and then re-encode it, you'll need to make sure you use the right encoding.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Python 2, you can simply change all your `str` objects to `unicode` objects. Unicode objects have all the same methods as strings but are encoded in a unicode format instead of ASCII. See http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#unicode .

If you are using Python 3, strings are encoded in UTF-8 by default.

Comment: `unicode` objects are sequences of unicode characters; they're not encoded in UTF-8 or any other encoding.

Comment: @Wooble: Technically, they're encoded in whatever encoding `Py_UNICODE` uses, which could be either UCS-2 or UCS-4 (I believe), depending on the implementation.

Comment: Alright, I'll edit my post in the interests of accuracy. But it is a relatively small detail in the context of the answer.

Comment: @Zhehao: it's a huge detail, as the fact that you need to encode them into some encoding for display is a major source of confusion and error messages.

Comment: @Wooble - No, I meant the exact encoding used is largely irrelevant. Obviously strings have an encoding. The fact that unicode objects are encoded in unicode is important. However, the exact type of unicode is  not so important in the context of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Python 2.6 or later, you can use the `io` library and its `io.open` method to open the files you want. It has an `encoding` argument which should be set to `'utf-8'` in your case. When you read or write the returned file objects, string are automatically en-/decoded.

Anyway, you don't need to do something special for ASCII, because UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you are only reading and writing to files and not expecting any other type of encoded input, then you should not have to do anything special.

```
% cat /tmp/u
π is 3.14.

% file /tmp/u
/tmp/u: UTF-8 Unicode text

% cat f.py
f = open('/tmp/u', 'r')
d = f.read()
print d.split()
f.close()

% python f.py 
['\xcf\x80', 'is', '3.14.']
```

This changes when you declare or accept standard input using UTF-8.

```
% cat g.py
s = 'π is 3.14.'
print s.split()

% python g.py
  File "g.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xcf' in file g.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

To handle this properly, declare the encoding for the Python program at the beginning per [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html) (referenced by the `SyntaxError` exception above).

```
% cat h.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
s = 'π is 3.14.'
print s.split()

% python h.py
['\xcf\x80', 'is', '3.14.']
```